# Kernel dies again and again in qiskit

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, quantum-computing, qiskit

I am running the following code on Qiskit using IBM Q experience's jupyter notebook here is the code :

```
%matplotlib inline
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries and configuring account
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, IBMQ,QuantumRegister,ClassicalRegister
from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from qiskit.visualization import *
# Loading your IBM Q account(s)
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
simulator=Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
qi=QuantumRegister(6)
qx=QuantumRegister(6)
qb=QuantumRegister(3)
qo=QuantumRegister(5)
qe=QuantumRegister(5)
v=QuantumRegister(1)
qd=QuantumRegister(3)
c=ClassicalRegister(9)
circuit=QuantumCircuit(qi,qx,qb,qe,qd,qo,v,c)
def fun_or(qc,q0,q1,q2):
    qc.x(q0)
    qc.x(q1)
    qc.ccx(q0,q1,q2)
    qc.x(q2)
    qc.x(q1)
    qc.x(q0)

def fun_and (qc,q0, q1, q2):
    qc.ccx( q0, q1, q2)
def fun_nand (qc,q0, q1, q2):
    fun_and(qc,q0,q1,q2)
    qc.x(q2)
def or3 (qc,q0, q1, q2, b, q3):
    fun_or(qc,q0, q1, b)
    fun_or(qc,b,q2,q3)
    qc.reset(b)
def or4 (qc,q0, q1, q2,q3, b1,b2,q4):
    or3(qc,q0, q1, q2,b1,b2)
    fun_or(qc,b2,q3,q4)
    qc.reset(b1)
    qc.reset(b2)
def or5 (qc,q0, q1, q2,q3,q4 ,b1,b2,b3,q5):
    or4(qc,q0, q1, q2,q3,b1,b2,b3)
    fun_or(qc,b3,q4,q5)
    qc.reset(b1)
    qc.reset(b2)
    qc.reset(b3)
def and3 (qc,q0, q1, q2, b, q3):
    fun_and(qc,q0,q1,b)
    fun_and(qc,b, q2, q3)
    qc.reset(b)
def and4 (qc,q0, q1, q2,q3, b1,b2, q4):
    and3(qc,q0,q1,q2,b1,b2)
    fun_and(qc,b2, q3, q4)
    qc.reset(b1)
    qc.reset(b2)
def and5 (qc,q0, q1, q2,q3,q4, b1,b2,b3, q5):
    and4(qc,q0,q1,q2,q3,b1,b2,b3)
    fun_and(qc,b3, q4, q5)
    qc.reset(b1)
    qc.reset(b2)
    qc.reset(b3)
#give inputs below






#give inputs above

for i in range (0,6):
    circuit.cx(qi[i],qx[i])
    circuit.x(qx[i])

# Bit one of digit
and3(circuit,qx[0],qx[1],qx[2],qb[0],qe[0])
and4(circuit,qx[0],qx[1],qx[3],qx[4],qb[0],qb[1],qe[1])
and4(circuit,qx[0],qx[2],qx[3],qi[5],qb[0],qb[1],qe[2])
and4(circuit,qx[2],qx[1],qx[3],qi[5],qb[0],qb[1],qe[3])
and4(circuit,qx[1],qx[2],qi[5],qx[4],qb[0],qb[1],qe[4])
and4(circuit,qx[0],qx[2],qi[5],qx[3],qb[0],qb[1],qo[0])
and4(circuit,qx[2],qx[1],qx[3],qi[4],qb[0],qb[1],qo[1])
and5(circuit,qx[1],qx[2],qx[5],qx[4],qi[3],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],qo[2])
and5(circuit,qx[0],qi[2],qi[5],qi[4],qi[3],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],qo[3])
and5(circuit,qx[0],qi[2],qx[5],qi[4],qx[3],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],v[0])
fun_and(circuit,v[0],qi[1],qo[4])
circuit.reset(v)
or5(circuit,qe[0],qe[1],qe[2],qe[3],qe[4],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],v[0])
circuit.reset(qe)
or5(circuit,qo[0],qo[1],qo[2],qo[3],qo[4],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],qe[0])
circuit.reset(qo)
fun_or(circuit,qe[0],v[0],qd[2])
circuit.measure(qd[2],c[2])
##############
#Second bit
and4(circuit,qx[0],qi[1],qx[2],qx[5],qb[0],qb[1],qe[0])
and4(circuit,qx[0],qi[1],qx[4],qx[5],qb[0],qb[1],qe[1])
and5(circuit,qx[0],qx[1],qi[2],qi[5],qx[4],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],qe[2])
and4(circuit,qx[0],qi[1],qi[3],qx[5],qb[0],qb[1],qe[3])
and5(circuit,qx[0],qi[1],qx[2],qi[3],qi[4],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],qe[4])
and5(circuit,qx[0],qx[1],qi[2],qx[5],qi[4],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],qo[0])
fun_and(circuit,qo[0],qx[3],qo[1])
and5(circuit,qx[0],qi[1],qi[2],qi[5],qi[4],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],qo[2])
fun_and(circuit,qo[2],qx[3],qd[1])
circuit.measure(qd[1],c[1])

circuit.reset(qe)
circuit.reset(qo)
#########
#Third Bit
and3(circuit,qx[0],qx[1],qx[2],qb[0],qe[0])
and3(circuit,qx[0],qx[1],qx[4],qb[0],qe[1])
and3(circuit,qx[0],qx[4],qx[5],qb[0],qe[2])
and4(circuit,qx[1],qx[2],qx[4],qx[5],qb[0],qb[1],qe[3])
and4(circuit,qx[0],qi[2],qi[3],qx[4],qb[0],qb[1],qe[4])
and5(circuit,qx[0],qi[2],qi[3],qi[4],qi[5],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],qo[0])
or5(circuit,qe[0],qe[1],qe[2],qe[3],qe[4],qb[0],qb[1],qb[2],qo[1])
fun_or(circuit,qo[1],qo[0],qd[0])
circuit.measure(qd[0],c[0])


#####################################
#circuit.measure(qi[0],c[0])
#circuit.measure(qi[1],c[1])
#circuit.measure(qi[2],c[2])

######################################

job = execute(circuit, simulator, shots=100)
print('#')
print(job.result())
result=job.result()
print('##')
counts = result.get_counts(circuit)
print('###')
circuit.draw()

print('111!!')
print("\nTotal count ",counts)
```

I am using IBM's Quantum Experience's Jupyter notebook. Whenever I hit run, the program runs for a few minutes before a dialog box appears saying that the kernel died. I don't what's causing this, maybe that the code is too much for qiskit?
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

When running on the Aer simulators, the code is run locally on your computer. This means that what you are able to do is bound by your own machine's hardware, specifically the RAM. Simulating almost 30 qubits locally is pretty straining, and is most likely the reason the kernel consistently dies.

I would suggest running your circuit through IBM's cloud simulator, `ibmq_qasm_simulator`. This simulator does not run locally on your computer, so you do not need to be worried about this issue.

To access IBM's computers, you would first need to set up an account. You need to create an IBMid account, go to [IBM Q Experience](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/), and then follow the steps listed [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html#access-ibm-q-systems).